# Hibernate mappedBy in aggregate associations, possible to use?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa

I am trying to figure out mappedBy ... If I have a Person { Address address; } then I can add a Person person in Address with mappedBy "address"... However, if Person has class Person { PersonDetails personDetails } and PersonDetails { Address address } then is there a way to do a mappedby back to the Person from Address ? How can I achieve this?

This setup is what is commonly used and works fine:

```
    class Person {
            @OneToOne
            Address address;
    }


    class Address {
            @OneToOne(mappedBy="address")
            Person person;
    }
```

The above will allow for person to automatically be set on Address when when new Person() is called.

However, can I do something along these lines, if so how? The below example doesn't work:

```
    class Person {
            @OneToOne
            PersonDetails personDetails;
    }

    class PersonDetails {
            @OneToOne
            Address address;
    }

    class Address {
            @OneToOne(mappedBy="IS THERE A WAY TO REFER TO THE PERSON THROUGH MY OWNER, PERSONDETAILS??")
            Person person;
    }
```

Do I have to manually set the person on Address when creating a new Person().

Is it possible to use @Column(table, or @JoinColumn in combination somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible using Hibernate or JPA.

Answer (score 1):

`mappedBy` is used to mark the other side of bidirectional relationship between two entities. So, it is not intended for the purpose you describe.

If you just want to access `Person` from `Address`, you can just do this

```
class Address {
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "address")
    PersonDetails personDetails;
    ...
    public Person getPerson() {
        return personDetails == null ? null : personDetails.getPerson();
    }
}
```

Comment: I was more looking for a way for hibernate to bind the person directly, as it does when mappedBy is used

Comment: I'm not aware of such possibility. Is there anything you can't achieve using this "chained getter"?